# Not able to handle error while using Flowable in Rxjava

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

```
Flowable.just(getSize())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .onExceptionResumeNext { Flowable.just(10) }
            .onErrorResumeNext(Flowable.just(10))
            .doOnError { throwable -> Logger.log("caught in doOnError") }
            .subscribe({ size -> showSizeOnUi(size) },
                    { throwable -> Logger.log("caught in onError") })
```

getSize() function will throw NullPointer Exception.

```
 private fun getSize(): Int {
    val path: String? = null
    return path!!.length  // attempts to call length on null string (path)
}
```

As far as i know, if getSize() throws any exception then controll should be given to the onExceptionResumeNext, which will then return '10'  and this value should go to the **onNext() "{ size -> showSizeOnUi(size) }"**. But in this case, app just crashes.
Can i prevent this crash through any fallback mechanism ?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding of `just`. It takes an **already existing value**. Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables#just

Comment: Thanks for the link. Now, I believe i have 2 choices. Defer and Callable.

Comment: In addition, seems it has to be a Single in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `Flowable.just(getSize())` will immediately throws NPE as @bob-dalgleish explains. But you could defer creation of `Flowable`:

```
    Flowable.defer { Flowable.just(getSize()) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .onExceptionResumeNext { Flowable.just(10) }
        .onErrorResumeNext(Flowable.just(10))
        .doOnError { throwable -> Logger.log("caught in doOnError") }
        .subscribe({ size -> showSizeOnUi(size) },
                { throwable -> Logger.log("caught in onError") })
```

Now `Flowable.just(getSize())` will be called on `subscribe()` and RxJava is able to catch the exception.

Comment: Thanks. Defer worked as i wanted. But now i am using  fromCallable{}, as i only want one time observable.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `Flowable.just(getSize())` will immediately throw the `NullPointerException` and there is no opportunity for RxJava to catch it.

You need to surround the whole statement with a `try {...} catch (...) {...}` block.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. Earlier I was using try catch block . But now i am looking for some in built mechanism for handling exception.